# Checking if two strings are the same, if they are, need to redo loop

Tags: c#, list, random

```
firstRound = (i + "&" + partnerOne);
secondRound = (i + "&" + partnerTwo);

while (firstRound.Equals(secondRound))
{
    myCount = myCount + 1;
    spotTwo = rnd.Next(heelerEntries.Count);
    partnerTwo = heelerEntriesTwo[spotTwo];
    secondRound = (i + "&" + partnerTwo);
    if (myCount == 5)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Messed up 5 times!");
        break;
    }
```

My problem is that sometimes when executing the code, i will end up with the same team "A&G" for round one, and "A&G" for round two. List 1 has ABCDEF and list 2 has GHIJKL. I want it to check the teams from both rounds, and if any are the same, redo the randomizing for the second round.

As seen in the code above, i am trying to see if the strings firstRound and secondRound are the same. If they are, i want it to redo the entire second round loop. The code is for randomizing teams from a list so i cannot have the same team for the different rounds. If anyone is able to help, or give me other ideas on ways to do this, i appreciate it.

Comment: Help with *what*, exactly?  You haven't described a problem you've encountered...

Comment: Sorry, i was too busy about making sure the code was in right, i added the issue.

Comment: You probably want to look into the round robin algorithm.  There are other hazards to random picks like A-B get matched several times but A-D and B-C never

Comment: Instead of choosing random teams from your lists, shuffle the lists first and then choose from 0 to length - 1.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I understand that, but at the same time, it can still pull the same team twice.

Comment: No, you can't. Not if the teams are unique in each list.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Okay, im lost now. I have 3 lists. Headers = {A,B,C,D,E,F}, Heelers = {G,H,I,J,K,L}, and Heelers2 = {G,H,I,J,K,L}. The program takes each item in headers and matches an item in heelers. Then it grabs each item from headers and matches it to a random item in heelers2, but i need it to be completely different combinations the second time.

Comment: That's not the same thing. Where did that 3rd list came from? You didn't write anything about a 3rd list in the question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I added it in the edit.

Comment: So you have two lists are the exact same? How do they all correlate? Id consider re writting your question and state your exact situation and your exact expected result and your code. Read your question when you're done and ask yourself if someone who has never seen your problem before will know what you're talking about.